# I want to fetch image from mysql to android listview using php json...?

Tags: android

```
> This is my MainActivity.java That receives all json data from the php file and converts into string format and print it in listview using string array but i have problem with bitmap image array
```

I want to add multiple items in listview like textview and image i dont have problem with textview it displays properly but with image it is not done

```
    package com.demo.php.listview;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null; 
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al3=new ArrayList<String>();
    String targetmonth;
    String targetyear;
    String targetamount;
    String Dphoto;
//  int responseCode;
    //int listItemCount=0;
    ListView listview ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setTheme(Color.WHITE); 
        setTitleColor(Color.rgb(0x74, 0, 0x37));
        setTitle("Doctor's List");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_RIGHT_ICON); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        new LoadData().execute();

    } 



    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
        @Override
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, ""," Loading...");  
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
            try{

                     listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                             al.toArray(new String[al.size()]),
                             al1.toArray(new String[al1.size()]),
                             al2.toArray(new String[al2.size()]),
                             al3.toArray(new Bitmap[al3.size()])));
                     this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            // HTTP post 
                    try { 
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                        try{
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/test.php");

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                        httppost.setEntity(se); 
                        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                        int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent(); 
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //buffered reader
                        try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                        String line = "0";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result = sb.toString();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        try{
                        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject json_data = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                            targetamount=json_data.getString("DName");
                            targetmonth=json_data.getString("Dspl");
                            targetyear = json_data.getString("Dedu"); 
                            Dphoto = json_data.getString("Dphoto");
                            al.add(targetmonth); 
                            al1.add(targetyear);
                            al2.add(targetamount);  
                            al3.add(Dphoto); 
                            //listItemCount=al2.size();

                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }   
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }  
                     catch (Exception e) {
                            //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }        
            return null; 
        }
    }



    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextItem.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } 


}


>This is my DataAdapter
```

I am not getting the image in Listview I am little bit confuse about the image  bitmap array please helps with that bitmap

```
    package com.demo.php.listview; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView; 
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String targetmonth;
    String targetyear;
    String targetamount; 
    //Bitmap Dphoto1;
    String[] month;
    String[] year;
    String[] amount;
    String[] Dphoto1;
    Bitmap[] Dphoto2;
    private String src;
public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month, String[] year, String[] amount,Bitmap[] Dphoto2) {
         //this.sta = sta;
    Bitmap[] = (Bitmap[]) getBitmapFromURL(Dphoto2);
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
        this.amount = amount; 
        this.Dphoto2=Dphoto2;
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    } 
    public int getCount() {
        return month.length;
    } 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Dname); 
            holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Dspl); 
            holder.amount = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Dedu);
            holder.Dphoto2=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Dphoto2);



            if (position == 0) {
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {

            holder.month.setText(month[position]);
            holder.year.setText(year[position]);
            holder.amount.setText(amount[position]);
            holder.Dphoto2.setImageBitmap(Dphoto2[position]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return convertView;
    } 
    private Object getBitmapFromURL(Bitmap[] dphoto2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView Dphoto2;
        public TextView Dphoto1;
        public ImageView Dphoto;
        TextView month;
        TextView year, amount; 
    }
    public class ImageLoadTask {

        public void execute(String dphoto1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }}
```

Comment: No. That will not work. But does this even compile? Which errors and exceptions do you get?

Comment: How many images will your app download? And what are their sizes?

Comment: More than 100 images

Comment: How much maximum? Please answer other question too. Are they bitmaps of jpg's or what are they?

Comment: only jpg's images i have

Comment: Near about 150 jpg images I want to load....!\

Comment: `And what are their sizes?` You are not going to inform us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON text will deliver a base64 encoded bitmap or jpg.

```
ArrayList<String> al3=new ArrayList<String>();
```

change that to:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> al3=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

And in the loop change:

```
al3.add(Dphoto);
```

to:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapFromBase64 (Dphoto);
al3.add(bitmap);
```

Remove:

```
Bitmap[] = (Bitmap[]) getBitmapFromURL(Dphoto2); // does not even compile!
```

You have to implement a function `decodeBitmapFromBase64()`. You can find code for it on this site.

Remove all Toast()s from doInBackground. They are not allowed there. Put them in onPostExecute instead.

Comment: You should not get it from some one. You should implement that function..And all three lines of code can be found many times on this site.

Comment: private Bitmap decodeBitmapFromBase64(Bitmap dphoto) {
    Bitmap immagex=dphoto;
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
       immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
       byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
       String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

       Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;

Comment: No. That is code to encode a bitmap to a base64 string. You need code to decode a base64 string to a bitmap. The reverse.